# Total differential of a function $F(x, y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I found this definition of total variation of a function $F(x, y)$
\begin{eqnarray}
dF(x, y) &\equiv& F(x+dx, y+dy) -F(x, y)\\
& = & [F(x+dx, y+dy) - F(x, y+dy)] + [F(x, y+dy) - F(x, y)] \\
& = & \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy
\end{eqnarray}

But I did not understand why $[F(x+dx, y+dy) - F(x, y+dy)]$ and $[F(x, y+dy) - F(x, y)]$ are equals to $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy$ respectively. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of partial derivative, it is the rate of change of the function with respect to some variable, while keeping all others fixed.

Therefore, at any x

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{F(x, y+dy) - F(x, y)}{dy}$$

Also, at any y
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{F(x+dx, y) - F(x, y)}{dx}$$

Now in the second expression we can replace $y$ with $y+dy$ everywhere, and it will still remain a partial derivative, but now evaluated at $y+dy$ instead of $y$, which is the same thing at this order. Thus
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{F(x+dx, y+dy) - F(x, y+dy)}{dx}$$